# HackerRank Project Euler #21: Amicable numbers

Tags: c

[Here](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler021) is the problem statement.

> Let *d(n)* be defined as the sum of proper divisors of n (numbers less than n which divide evenly into n).
>
> If *d(a)=b* and *d(b)=a*, where *a≠b*, then a and b are an amicable pair and each of a and b are called amicable numbers.
>
> For example, the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110 therefore d(220)=284. The proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142 so d(284)=220.
>
> Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under N.

Here is my code with brute force

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int sum(long long int n)
{
    long long int i, sum=0;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
            sum+=i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        long long int n;
        scanf("%lld",&n);
        long long int i,sum1=0;
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(sum(sum(i))==i&&sum(i)!=i)
                sum1+=i;
        }
        printf("%lld\n",sum1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code works, but very slow. Therefore, I implemented a faster algorithm.

This algorithm will find the sum of divisors of its prime factors and multiply them. Proof of this algorithm [here](http://mathschallenge.net/library/number/sum_of_divisors). Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int power(long long int x, long long int y)
{
    long long int i,a=1;
    for(i=1;i<=y;i++)
        a*=x;
    return a;
}

long long int sumOfPrimeDivisors(long long int p, long long int a)
{
    long long int x;
    x=(power(p,a+1)-1)/(p-1);
    return x;
}

long long int isPrime(long long int n)
{
    long long int i,flag=1;
    for(i=2;i*i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            flag=0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

void primeDivisors(long long int n, long long int b[], int *k)
{
    long long int i;
    *k=0;
    for(i=2;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0 && isPrime(i))
        {
        b[(*k)++]=i;
        }
    }
}

long long int primeDivisorCount(long long int n, long long int p)
{
    long long int count=0;
    while(n%p==0)
    {
        count++;
        n/=p;
    }
    return count;
}

long long int sum(long long int n)
{
    long long int ans=1,b[15];
    int k,i;

    primeDivisors(n,b,&k);

    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        ans*=sumOfPrimeDivisors(b[i],primeDivisorCount(n,b[i]));

    return ans-n;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        long long int n;
        scanf("%lld",&n);

        printf("%lld %lld\n",sum(n),sum(sum(n)));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives correct output for `n=220 (284 220)`. But when I replace the `printf` with

```
long long int i;

        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(sum(sum(i))==i && sum(i)!=i )
                printf("%lld\n",i);
        }
```

I get all junk values for output.

For example,

> **Input**
>
> ```
> 1
> 9949
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> ```
> -9948
> ```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What numbers did your code print that it shouldn't have? What do `sum(i)` and `sum(sum(i))` give for those numbers?

Comment: i get a lot of junk values for `i`. one of them is `9949` gives output `-9948 9949`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

```
if(sum(sum(i))==i && sum(i)!=i )
```

to

```
if(sum(sum(i))==i && sum(i)!=i && sum(i)>0)
```

helped in giving right output.

Comment: This is just working around the bug that gives you negative numbers rather than fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of printf :

```
   long long int i; 
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(sum(sum(i))==i && sum(i)!=i && !isPrime(i))
            printf("%lld\n",i);
    }
```

Previously all other prime numbers were also being displayed.